# Why do PKCS#1 PublicKeys from 'Java17 KeyFactory' and Swift (iOS) differ?

Tags: java, ios, swift, encryption, public-key-encryption

## Update (tl;dr)

- **Swift** (iOS) produces PKCS#1-formatted keys
- **Java** 17 produces keys which look alike but are slightly different using the **SubjectPublicKeyInfo** (or SPKI) specification, following [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.7)

---

## Objective

Creating equally formatted public keys in PKCS#1-format

### General approach

I am generating 4096 RSA public keys, in both ...

- Java 17
- Swift in iOS emulator (iPhone 14)

Samples of the subsequent generated and keys can be found in the **Appendix**.

#### Sample Code: Generating a KeyPair (Swift - iOS)

```swift
// Keypair attributes
let tag = "my_personal_keystore_keypair_alias".data(using: .utf8)!
let attributes: [String: Any] =
    [kSecAttrKeyType as String:            kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
     kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:      "4096",
     kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String:
        [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String:    true,
         kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag]
]
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

// Generate PrivateKey / Keypair
guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error) else {
    throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
}

// Extract PublicKey
guard let publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey),
      let publicKeyOptional = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey, nil) else {
    return "PublicKey could not be accessed."
}
let publicKeyData = publicKeyOptional as Data
let base64PublicKey = publicKeyData.base64EncodedString()
print("PublicKey, base64:   ", base64PublicKey)
```

#### Sample Code: Generating a KeyPair (Java 17)

```java
private static String getPublicKey() {
    KeyPairGenerator generator;
    try {
        generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new EncryptionException(e);
    }
    generator.initialize(4096);
    KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pair.getPublic().getEncoded());
}
```

## Aim - Parsing the keys in Java 17

Contrary to the assumption that the keys are formatted equally, the Java-side code is only capable to read the keys generated by Java itself.

### Solution for keys generated by Java 17

Parsing the key(s) generated by Java 17:

```java
public Optional<PublicKey> validateKeyFromJava(String publicKey) {
    try {
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(EncryptionProperties.ALGORITHM);
        EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
        return Optional.ofNullable(keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

### Problem: Parsing the keys generated via Swift (iOS)

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence
> at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:241)
> at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:351)

#### NOT WANTED - Workaround for keys generated via Swift (iOS)

Using an external dependency ..

> import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;

.. it is possible to parse the iOS keys as well.
The key can thereafter be used to properly encrypt 'payload' ...

Parsing the key(s) generated via Swift (iOS):

```java
public Optional<PublicKey> validateKeyFromIOS (String publicKeyANS1) {
    try {
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyANS1);

        ASN1Sequence sequence = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(publicKeyBytes);
        ASN1Integer modulus = ASN1Integer.getInstance(sequence.getObjectAt(0));
        ASN1Integer exponent = ASN1Integer.getInstance(sequence.getObjectAt(1));
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus.getPositiveValue(),
                exponent.getPositiveValue());

        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance(EncryptionProperties.ALGORITHM);

        return Optional.ofNullable(factory.generatePublic(keySpec));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        String errorInfo = "iOS-PublicKey - Erwarteter Algorithmus: RSA, Retrieved: " +
                e.getMessage();
        sendToErrorQueue(e, errorInfo);
        return Optional.empty();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
        sendToErrorQueue(e, "Der iOS-PublicKey entspricht nicht der erwarteten Specification.");
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

... Still it is a different way to read the keys.
Therefore the keys have to be somehow different.

#### Wrapping up

Both systems produce keys which are PKCS#1-formatted.
This can be examined (see Appendix)
The keys are somewhat different.

## Questions to be answered:

1. What is the difference?
2. Major - is it possible to generate public keys in Swift (iOS) alike those in Java 17?
3. Minor - is it possible for Java 17 to read the keys generated by Swift (iOS) without the BouncyCastle dependency?

- Aim: Reduction of switches in the code for different input paths.

## Appendix

All keys may be analyzed:

- https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp

Multiple keys are given to prevent 'lucky shots' ..  ;-)

### Sample keys - Swift iOS

First:

> 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

Second:

> 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

### Sample keys - Java 17

First:

> 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

Second:

> 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

Comment: Java does **not** encode public keys using the PKCS1 format, instead it uses an arguably more common (and better) standard called SubjectPublicKeyInfo (or SPKI) format, specified in [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.7). This standard is supported by many software packages, not just Java.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PresidentJamesK.Polk .. :) ... This little comment untied a huge knot I was carrying around .. :D

Answer (score 0):

## Why ... .. .

By today I have at least a **guess WHY** the keys differ.
If I had to categorize those two types ..

- Public-Key Cryptography Standards (**PKCS**)
- Simple public key infrastructure (**SPKI**)

.. it would look like follows:

```
ASN.1 object
├── Human readable & File-oriented
│   ├── base64
│   │   └── PEM
│   └── binary
│       ├── BER
│       └── DER
└── Compile time-oriented
    └── SPKI
```

The ASN.1-object is the upper level container ([Definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A)).

PEM, DER and BER are file-oriented representations of the key ([Source](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/manpki/pki_asn1objects.html)).

#### PKCS#1 in PEM

```
Theory:
-----Header----
$ Base65 encoded Key (Here: PKCS#1
-----Footer-----

Praxis:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIHgMIGaAgEBMA0GCSqG...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Header and Footer contain meta-information about the delivered key, here: *RSA PRIVATE KEY*
This makes the key more likely to be human-readable - at least regarding the key administration 'by hand'.

#### SPKI

I assume that this meta-information is encoded within the SPKI-format. Therefore there is no further meta-information needed to parse the key. On the other hand this information can not be obtained easily without further knowledge. The human-readability is largely limited.

Hence:

- Choose the key-format regarding your purpose.
  ** For *machine-to-machine communication* **SPKI** might be the better choice.
  ** For key administration which include human interaction, PEM seems a good choice.

Afterall, in terms of security the two formats do not differ.

## How ... .. .

More specifically, the **HOW** can be answered ...

... the subsequent analysis stems from Java 17.
The information provided by Java is seen **here** as the 'ground truth'. ... ;-)

### Analyze keys generated by Java itself

```java
// Static inputs
String algorithm = "RSA";
int keySize = 4096;

// Key generation
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
generator.initialize(keySize);
KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();

// Analysis
System.out.println("----- PublicKey information -----");
System.out.println("PublicKey algorithm: " + pair.getPublic().getAlgorithm());
System.out.println("PublicKey format: " + pair.getPublic().getFormat());

System.out.println("----- PrivateKey information -----");
System.out.println("PrivateKey algorithm: " + pair.getPrivate().getAlgorithm());
System.out.println("PrivateKey format: " + pair.getPrivate().getFormat());
```

Output:

```bash
----- PublicKey information -----
PublicKey algorithm: RSA
PublicKey format: X.509
----- PrivateKey information -----
PrivateKey algorithm: RSA
PrivateKey format: PKCS#8
```

### Conclusion

#### Java

- Java generates its **PublicKeys** in the **x.509**-format.
- PrivateKeys are generated in the PKCS#8-format.

#### Swift

- Swift generates its **PublicKeys** in the **PKCS#1**-format.

These findings match the following answer in the apple-developer forum:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/85915